# Creating Duplicate Elements in an Array using Higher-Order Functions

Tags: d

New to D Language here. I'm trying to use higher-order functions (i.e. fold!, reduce!, filter!, map!) to create duplicates of array elements. I'm declaring my generic function as pure and trying to accomplish this task as a one line function. The closest I've come so far is

```
auto dupList(T)(T[] list) pure { (return map!(a => a.repeat(2)); }
```

but this gives me the following output

```
[[1,1],[2,2]]
```

instead of what I'm actually wanting

```
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

I'm calling the function like so

```
writeln(dupList(nums));
```

Instead of using map, I've been trying to use reduce in its place but when I switch out map for reduce I get the following errors:

```
Error instantiated from here: `staticMap!(ReduceSeedType, __lambda2)` C:\D\dmd2\src\phobos\std\algorithm\iteration.d 3287
Error: template `D_Programs.duplist!int.duplist.__lambda2` cannot deduce function from argument types `!()(int, int)`, candidates are:  C:\D\dmd2\src\phobos\std\algorithm\iteration.d 3696
Error: template instance `D_Programs.duplist!int.duplist.F!(__lambda2)` error instantiating     C:\D\dmd2\src\phobos\std\meta.d 803
Error instantiated from here: `reduce!(int[])` D_Programs.d (refers to dupList)
Error `D_Programs.duplist!int.duplist.__lambda2` D_Programs.d (refers to dupList)
Error instantiated from here: `duplist!int` D_Programs.d (refers to where I'm calling from)
```

Any help/advice on understanding at least the top three errors and where I'm going wrong with my function would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` essentially replaces each element with the result of calling the passed function on that element. Since your function returns an array of two `int`s, the result will be an array of arrays, each element holding two `int`s.

Armed with this knowledge, we can use [`std.algorith.iteration.joiner`](https://dlang.org/library/std/algorithm/iteration/joiner.html):

```
auto dupList(T)(T[] list) pure { return list.map!(a => a.repeat(2)).joiner; }
```

As you note, it should also be possible to use `reduce`, but it's a bit more complicated:

```
auto dupList(T)(T[] list) pure { return reduce!((a,b) => a~b~b)((T[]).init, list); }
```

The reasons it's more complicated are:

1) `reduce`'s function takes two arguments - the result of reducing thus far, and the next element.

2) `reduce` assumes the first element of the passed array is the starting point for reduction, unless a seed value is passed. Since the first element is a `T`, not a `T[]`, we will need to pass a seed value. `[]` won't do, since it's typed as `void[]`, so we will need to create an empty `T[]`. This can be done either with `new T[0]`, or as above, `(T[]).init`.

Hope this helps - if there are any more questions, please ask! :)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you meant to call `map!(a => a.repeat(2))(list)` or `list.map!(a=>a.repeat(2))` (both are the same) since if you don't pass the actual list to the function, it isn't ever actually being called!

Anyway, neither map nor reduce will do what you want on their own. Map transforms individual elements, but can neither add nor remove elements. Reduce (and btw fold, they are basically the same) runs through the array and... well, reduces it down to just one element, like a sum function turning the array 1,2,3 into the single element, 6. Since you want to add elements, you are going to need something else outside.

But first, a sidestep: your call to reduce is failing to compile because it is being passed incorrect arguments (or something, tbh the error messages are really bad and hard to read without having the code they directly refer to open too, but it definitely refers to a lambda). Passing it your `dupList` won't work because `dupList` takes an array, but reduce works with just two elements at a time, for example, `sum(a, b)`.

Anyway, back to the main point, the closest you can get is perhaps running another function outside map to flatten the resulting array, or in other words, join them together. There's a function for that: http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.algorithm.iteration.joiner.2.html

Suggesting a possible answer:

```
    return list .map!(a => a.repeat(2)) .joiner;
```

BTW: one line functions are grossly overrated. You are often better off writing it on multiple lines, even if as a single statement, if nothing else but so you can get unique line numbers on the error messages. I would prefer to write this out probably something like this:

```
    return
            list
                    .map!(a => a.repeat(2))
                    .joiner
            ;
```

so each line represents a single step of the process. The exact formatting, of course, is up to you, but I like this more stretched out approach for (slightly) nicer error messages and an easier view when editing to add comments or more stuff before, after, in the middle, whatever.